# Persistent Memory Redundancy?

Tags: memory, intel, hpe

This is the first time I've really dug into PMMs (Intel Optane), so bear with me if I'm a little slow on the uptake.  It looks like you can configure these in either cache- or disk-mode, depending on your system.  As one who wants to add disk-mode PMMs to their environment but has concerns about redundancy, what happens in the event of a PMM failure?  It seems as though there's no way to set up something akin to a hardware RAID for PMMs, but is there any other way to get redundancy at the hardware level?  The only options I've found are software-based, which doesn't seem great.  System in question is a DL360 Gen10.

Quickspecs mentions nothing: https://www.hpe.com/psnow/doc/a00008159enus.pdf

Other HPE memory guides mention nothing: https://www.hpe.com/psnow/doc/a00017079enw

Configuration tutorials on youtube mention nothing.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AqqymYPAfWk

What would be a use case for PMMs in disk mode? Am I missing something?

This doc from Intel says hardware-based redundancy is not possible:  https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/developer/articles/technical/speeding-up-io-workloads-with-intel-optane-dc-persistent-memory-modules.html

Cheers,

Answer (score 2):

> what happens in the event of a PMM failure

It is gone. If wou want redundancy, set up redundancy (i.e. RAID 1)

> The only options I've found are software-based, which doesn't seem great

Why? Mirroring is trivial on the CPU - just submit a write command for the same data to both endpoints. Software is WAY better for that use case than hardware.